# Поиск TypeORM в БД PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Всем привет!

Подскажите, возможно ли средствами TypeORM в Nest.js выполнить запрос на поиск, чтобы он нашел все статусы "Closed" в БД. Пробовал через **.findAndCount** (для пагинации) строить запрос, но никак не пойму сути.

p.s. рабочий запрос из PosgreSQL:

```
SELECT "status" FROM public.order WHERE "status" @> '[{"status":"Closed"}]';
```

p.p.s.

Сущность в PostgreSQL:
таблица - "Order";
колонка - "Status":

```
    [
      {
        "status": "Closed",
        "createdAt": "2023-02-14T14:09:26.322Z"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: покажите определение энтити Order и `\d "order"` в postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Оператор Like](https://typeorm.io/find-options#advanced-options)

```
import {Like} from 'typeorm';

const res = await connection.getRepository(Order).findAndCount({
    where: {
        status: Like("%Closed%")
    }
});
```

Либо

```
const res = await dataSource
    .getRepository(Order)
    .createQueryBuilder("order")
    .where("order.status like 'Closed'")
    .getMany();
```

Comment: Либо я что-то не то делаю, но постман пишет:
"message": "оператор не существует: json ~~ unknown"

Comment: @alexander что-то не то делаете. Какой-то оператор json) Тут его вообще нет

Comment: У меня такой запрос:
const orders = await this.findAndCount({
      where: {
        status: orderStatus ? Like("%Closed%") : null,
      },
      order: { id: "DESC" },
      take: size,
      skip: (page - 1) * size,
    });

Comment: Ладно, теперь он выдаёт:
 "message": "оператор не существует: jsonb ~~ unknown",

Comment: @alexander попробуйте начать с where, потом добавьте order, потом take...

Comment: Вот так пишет в pgAdmin

SELECT "status" FROM public.order WHERE "status" Like '%Closed%'

ERROR: ОШИБКА:  оператор не существует: jsonb ~~ unknown
LINE 1: SELECT "status" FROM public.order WHERE "status" Like '%Clos...
                                                         ^
HINT:  Оператор с данными именем и типами аргументов не найден. Возможно, вам следует добавить явные приведения типов.

Comment: @alexander попробуйте без like.  Напишите просто status: "Closed"

Comment: В таком случае мне приходит просто пустой массив...

Comment: @alexander я дописал второй вариант. Попробуйте

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143054/discussion-between-alexander-and-alexander-chernin).

Comment: **const res = await this.dataSource
      .getRepository("order")
      .createQueryBuilder("order")
      .where(`order.status @> '[{"status": "Closed"}]'`)
      .getMany();**
Вот такой вариант сработал для меня